# как настроить автоформатирование на текущий метод? Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Россия. Android Studio. Наши дни.

:)

При работе в Android Studio нажимаешь ctrl+alt+L и форматируется весь текст класса.
как настроить автоформатирование только на текущий метод?

Comment: чем плохо, что отфарматируется весь класс? операция занимает доли секунды и что в вашем понимании "текущий метод"

Comment: текущий метод тот в котором я работаю сейчас. public void addFish(){/* я тут работаю */}

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

Для автоформатирования только определенной части кода нужно ее выделить, нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> и потом выбрать нужную опцию в появившемся диалоге.

Comment: как же так, не может быль чтобы googloвцы не предусмотрели этого. По поводу выделения это да, но не удобно.